# Rspec Test for Regular Expression

Tags: ruby, regex, rspec

*I am still very new to testing

Code (simply returns a number if it's three digits or less)

File name: example.rb

```
def separate_comma(number)
  str_array_length <= 3 ? (return number) : (return false)
end
```

Rspec

File name: spec_example.rb

```
require_relative "example"
require 'rspec'

def random_num(min, max)
   rand(max - min + 1) + min
end

describe "separate_comma" do
   it "returns no comma, when the integer is smaller than 1000" do
     expect(separate_comma(random_num(0, 999))).to match(/^\d{1,3}$/)
   end
end
```

Whenever I run this, I get the error:

```
./spec_example.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any suggestions? I believe something is wrong with the regular expression, so I tried match(/\d{13}/) and that failed too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure about the `require`-related error, but you're trying to run a `match`-matcher for your regex against a `Fixnum` (the return value from your call to [`Kernel#rand`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-rand)), rather than a `String`:

```
irb(main)> "111".match(/^\d{1,3}$/)
=> #<MatchData "111">
irb(main)> 111.match(/^\d{1,3}$/)
NoMethodError: undefined method `match' for 111:Fixnum
```

So, I got your code to work with the following changes (I assumed the `str_array_length` was the length of the passed in number as a string):

```
def separate_comma(number)
  number = number.to_s
  number.length <= 3 ? (return number) : (return false)
end

def random_num(min, max)
  rand(max - min + 1) + min
end

describe "separate_comma" do
  it "returns no comma, when the integer is smaller than 1000" do
    expect(separate_comma(random_num(0, 999))).to match(/\A\d{1,3}\z/)
  end
end
```